# Get current stack trace from running process

Tags: delphi, stack-trace

I have an Delphi app with jdbg file inside the binary (using MakeJclDbg from JCLDebug) and I need to get the current stack trace (not necessary from an exception) outside the application, from another app. Is there any way to do it? Today we already do this mannualy using TJclTD32InfoScanner class, but that does not work with jdbg inside the binary.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6040777/6137384) of Andre, I [downloaded](https://github.com/andremussche/asmprofiler) the source of AsmProfiler (which I already used) and used its classes TProcessSampler and TThreadSampler from units mcProcessSampler and mcThreadSampler. I was able to export this to a separated project and test the application. I want to thank Andre for the effort and well made profiler.